# The command could not be located because '/sbin' is not included in the PATH environment variable

Tags: ifconfig, lxterminal

I have a severe problem today: when I type `ifconfig` it does not show ip configuration on ubuntu 12.04. Can anyone help me on this?

Here is the result of `ifconfig`:

```
Command 'ifconfig' is available in '/sbin/ifconfig'
The command could not be located because '/sbin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
This is most likely caused by the lack of administrative privileges associated with your user account.
ifconfig: command not found
```

Comment: Do you have superuser privileges?

Comment: Jobin i have super user priveleges.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Try this command :

```
sudo ln -s /sbin/ifconfig /usr/bin/ifconfig
```

Comment: This isn't a solution, its a workaround.

Answer (score 33):

You can do either of the following:

- Open your `~/.bashrc` file and write the following to the end:

  ```bsh
  export PATH=$PATH:/sbin
  ```

and then do `source ~/.bashrc` or open a new terminal instance.

- or open your `/etc/environment` and add `/sbin` to end of the `PATH` variable, so that is as follows:

  ```bsh
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/sbin"
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Add `/sbin`  to the system path by running,

```
export PATH=$PATH:/sbin
```

If you follow @nux's answer, you have to create symbolic links for all the command files which are presented inside `/sbin` directory.But if you follow this or @jobin's answer, you don't need to go for that.

Comment: You don't need to source when you export on the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add `/sbin` to your path environment variable

1. Create a new file in `/etc/profile.d/custom-envs.sh` (**file must ends with .sh**)

   set the following file content:

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:/sbin
   ```
2. Add execute permissions

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /etc/profile.d/custom-envs.sh
   ```

To apply changes, you'll need to logout and login again