# After Permission & Ownership Changes system starts giving me errors

Tags: permissions, ftp

All problems started when I changed ownership and permission with `gksu nautilus` from the `ETC` and `SBIN` folder. After realizing what I had done, I followed some online threads and I've put back `chmod` and `chown` to the way it's supposed to be. Some problems were resolved.

##### 1st problem:

> Command '<command' is available in '/sbin/'
> The command could not be located because '/sbin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
> This is most likely caused by the lack of administrative privileges associated with your user account.
> : command not found

The same error is found in this question: [The command could not be located because '/sbin' is not included in the PATH environment variable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433092/the-command-could-not-be-located-because-sbin-is-not-included-in-the-path-env/433098#433098?newreg=84fd9e78f9ba4aeabf8d14d48d6258ad)

The solution they gave me in that link did not work for me. I have the following code in my environment file: `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

##### 2nd problem:

When I type `sudo su` I get:

> unable to stat /etc/sudoers.d/README: no such file or directory

##### 3rd problem:

FileZilla won't give me permission to the FTP to my Linux server, even when I use the IP address which should work.

##### 4th problem:

My host name stopped working for local computers on the network, the IP address does work, and I can see my files from the IP address.

---

##### Update

I executed the following commands from https://askubuntu.com/questions/308939/how-to-reset-default-permissions-for-etc:

```
$ sudo su
# chown -R root:root /etc
# find /etc -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
# find /etc -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
# chmod 755 /etc/init.d/* /etc/rc.local /etc/network/* /etc/cron.*/*
```

Things started working. However I might have done something in the process and now I get an error message when I open the terminal:

> There was an error creating the child process for this terminal.
> Getpt failed: Permission denied.

I still have access to my terminal, I haven't closed it yet. Any fix for that before I close my terminal?

##### Update

I fixed everything, however network-manager doesn't start on boot. There is no internet connection unless I type in terminal start network-manager. I use this computer as a server. I need a solution.

Comment: " I changed ownership and permission with gksu nautilus from the ETC and SBIN" It might help if you tell us what the change was. But I would suggest to consider a re-install (without formatting the disk). That is a guaranteed working method. Manually changing the permissions is possible but you need to do that from a live dvd and will be a lot of manual work.

Comment: i believe it was owner permission and the read write. Its fix now but i have a new problem. check update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Files inside /bin/ need to be 755 except for symlinks those needs to be 777 and all are owned by root:root.
- Files inside /etc/  need to be 644 and owned by root:root except for (if you have any of these that is):

  -rw-r----- 1 root     daemon      144 2007-02-20 13:41 at.deny
  drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root       4096 2007-11-14 11:01 libpaper.d
  -rw-r----- 1 root     fuse        216 2008-02-26 18:25 fuse.conf
  drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root       4096 2008-03-26 18:23 lsb-base
  drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root       4096 2008-04-01 14:45 jvm.d

  (there might be other files for you). Again: symlinks those needs to be 777. directories need to to be 755.

With this you should be able to manually reset them from a live dvd. If you have a 2nd similar operating system it is also possible to copy the permissons from that system. [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/356946/276585) from jlovi can be used to create a file with the permission in them. And executed on the broken system to restore the permissions.

If this is not possible you can also re-install without formatting. That will keep your documents safe but will re-install the Ubuntu system files.

Comment: Can you please give me some guidance in terminal.

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question, i don't know what this is. can you please explain? -rw-r----- 1 root daemon 144 2007-02-20 13:41 at.deny drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2007-11-14 11:01 libpaper.d -rw-r----- 1 root fuse 216 2008-02-26 18:25 fuse.conf drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2008-03-26 18:23 lsb-base drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2008-04-01 14:45 jvm.d

(there might be other files for you). Again: symlinks those needs to be 777. directories need to to be 755.